# How to set a title above each marker which represents a same label

Tags: python, matplotlib, label, legend, markers

I have a first version of legend in the following plot :

[image: 2 columns into legend]

with the following code :

```
# Plot and save : kmax = 0.3
p11, = plt.plot([0], marker='None',
               linestyle='None', label='$k_{max} = 0.3$')
p1, = plt.plot(FoM_vs_Density_array_1[:,0],FoM_vs_Density_array_1[:,1], '-b', label = '$GC_{sp}$')
p2, = plt.plot(FoM_vs_Density_array_1[:,0],FoM_vs_Density_array_1[:,2], '-r', label = '$GC_{ph}$')
p3, = plt.plot(FoM_vs_Density_array_1[:,0],FoM_vs_Density_array_1[:,3], '-y', label = '$WL$')
p4, = plt.plot(FoM_vs_Density_array_1[:,0],FoM_vs_Density_array_1[:,4], '-g', label = '$GC_{ph} + WL + XC$')
p5, = plt.plot(FoM_vs_Density_array_1[:,0],FoM_vs_Density_array_1[:,5], '-m', label = \

                                                               '$GC_{sp} + (GC_{ph} + WL + XC)$')
# Plot and save : kmax = 1.0
p12, = plt.plot([0], marker='None',
               linestyle='None', label='$k_{max} = 1.0$')
p6, = plt.plot(FoM_vs_Density_array_2[:,0],FoM_vs_Density_array_2[:,1], '--b', label = '$GC_{sp}$')
p7, = plt.plot(FoM_vs_Density_array_2[:,0],FoM_vs_Density_array_2[:,2], '--r', label = '$GC_{ph}$')
p8, = plt.plot(FoM_vs_Density_array_2[:,0],FoM_vs_Density_array_2[:,3], '--y', label = '$WL$')
p9, = plt.plot(FoM_vs_Density_array_2[:,0],FoM_vs_Density_array_2[:,4], '--g', label = '$GC_{ph} + WL + XC$')
p10, =plt.plot(FoM_vs_Density_array_2[:,0],FoM_vs_Density_array_2[:,5], '--m', label = \

                                                               '$GC_{sp} + (GC_{ph} + WL + XC)$')
plt.legend(fontsize=14, loc='best', ncol=2, handleheight=1.4, labelspacing=0.05)
```

As you can see, I put a title (`k_max = 0.3` and `k_max = 1.0`) for each column of markers and columns.

Now, to avoid this redundancy, I am trying to merge all duplicated labels while keeping the title for each marker by doing :

```
from matplotlib.legend_handler import HandlerTuple

# Plot and save : kmax = 0.3
p11, = plt.plot([0], marker='None', linestyle='None')
p1, = plt.plot(FoM_vs_Density_array_1[:,0],FoM_vs_Density_array_1[:,1], '-b')
p2, = plt.plot(FoM_vs_Density_array_1[:,0],FoM_vs_Density_array_1[:,2], '-r')
p3, = plt.plot(FoM_vs_Density_array_1[:,0],FoM_vs_Density_array_1[:,3], '-y')
p4, = plt.plot(FoM_vs_Density_array_1[:,0],FoM_vs_Density_array_1[:,4], '-g')
p5, = plt.plot(FoM_vs_Density_array_1[:,0],FoM_vs_Density_array_1[:,5], '-m')

# Plot and save : kmax = 1.0
p12, = plt.plot([0], marker='None', linestyle='None')
p6, = plt.plot(FoM_vs_Density_array_2[:,0],FoM_vs_Density_array_2[:,1], '--b') 
p7, = plt.plot(FoM_vs_Density_array_2[:,0],FoM_vs_Density_array_2[:,2], '--r') 
p8, = plt.plot(FoM_vs_Density_array_2[:,0],FoM_vs_Density_array_2[:,3], '--y') 
p9, = plt.plot(FoM_vs_Density_array_2[:,0],FoM_vs_Density_array_2[:,4], '--g') 
p10, = plt.plot(FoM_vs_Density_array_2[:,0],FoM_vs_Density_array_2[:,5], '--m') 

l = plt.legend([(p1,p6), (p2,p7), (p3,p8), (p4,p9), (p5,p10)], ['$GC_{sp}$', \
               '$GC_{ph}$', '$WL$', '$GC_{ph} + WL + XC$', '$GC_{sp} + (GC_{ph} + WL + XC)$'], \
               fontsize=14, loc='best', handlelength=2.5, handleheight=1.4, labelspacing=0.05, \
               handler_map={tuple: HandlerTuple(ndivide=None)})
```

This way, I get the following figure :

[image: same labels for 2 markers]

Then, 2 issues occurs :

**1)** The space between 2 markers is too small compared to the first figure above : how to insert a bigger space between markers and more length for the markers themselves (for example, having 4 dash-lines for the dash-line marker, like for the 4 dash-lines marker on the legend of the first figure above at the beginning of my post)

**2)** How to put the titles `k_max = 0.3` and `k_max = 1.0` above each column of markers ? : this way, I could identify quickly the case I consider on the plot (like I did on the first figure above but there was redundancy by repeating twice the displaying of all labels).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To tackle your issues you can try the following:

1.1 To increase the space between the markers you can provide the additional parameter `pad` to `HandlerTuple()` (from [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/legend_handler_api.html#matplotlib.legend_handler.HandlerTuple)). It will adjust the spacing between the different marker sections. This will look like:

```py
l = plt.legend(..., handler_map={tuple: HandlerTuple(ndivide=None, pad=2)})
```

1.2 To add more width to the markers you could increase the value for the `handlelength` parameter like this:

```py
l = plt.legend(..., handlelength=6.5, ...)
```

The resulting with these values will look like this:
[image: Part 1 solution]

2. To specify a description above the marker columns you can modify your `p11, = plt.plot([0], marker='None', linestyle='None')` and `p12, = plt.plot([0], marker='None', linestyle='None')` lines to the following:

```py
# your code:
# p11, = plt.plot([0], marker='None', linestyle='None')
# p12, = plt.plot([0], marker='None', linestyle='None')
p11, = plt.plot([], marker='$0.3$', linestyle='None', color='k', markersize=18, mec='None')
p12, = plt.plot([], marker='$1.0$', linestyle='None', color='k', markersize=18, mec='None')
```

Replacing `[0]` with an empty list `[]` will result in really nothing is plotted.
`mec='None'` will remove the markers edge color. Without it, the markers look like written in bold.

To show these "lines" in the legend add the following to legend:

```py
l = plt.legend([(p11,p12), ....], ['$k_{max}$', ...], ...)
```

With these adjustments the legend should look like:

[image: Part 2 solution]

The complete code should then look like this:

```py
# Plot and save : kmax = 0.3
p11, = plt.plot([], marker=r'$0.3$', linestyle='None', color='k', markersize=18, mec='None')
p1, = plt.plot(FoM_vs_Density_array_1[:,0],FoM_vs_Density_array_1[:,1], '-b')
p2, = plt.plot(FoM_vs_Density_array_1[:,0],FoM_vs_Density_array_1[:,2], '-r')
p3, = plt.plot(FoM_vs_Density_array_1[:,0],FoM_vs_Density_array_1[:,3], '-y')
p4, = plt.plot(FoM_vs_Density_array_1[:,0],FoM_vs_Density_array_1[:,4], '-g')
p5, = plt.plot(FoM_vs_Density_array_1[:,0],FoM_vs_Density_array_1[:,5], '-m')

# Plot and save : kmax = 1.0
p12, = plt.plot([], marker='$1.0$', linestyle='None', color='k', markersize=18, mec='None')
p6, = plt.plot(FoM_vs_Density_array_2[:,0],FoM_vs_Density_array_2[:,1], '--b')
p7, = plt.plot(FoM_vs_Density_array_2[:,0],FoM_vs_Density_array_2[:,2], '--r')
p8, = plt.plot(FoM_vs_Density_array_2[:,0],FoM_vs_Density_array_2[:,3], '--y')
p9, = plt.plot(FoM_vs_Density_array_2[:,0],FoM_vs_Density_array_2[:,4], '--g')
p10, = plt.plot(FoM_vs_Density_array_2[:,0],FoM_vs_Density_array_2[:,5], '--m')

l = plt.legend([(p11,p12),(p1,p6), (p2,p7), (p3,p8), (p4,p9), (p5,p10)], ['$k_{max}$','$GC_{sp}$', \
               '$GC_{ph}$', '$WL$', '$GC_{ph} + WL + XC$', '$GC_{sp} + (GC_{ph} + WL + XC)$'], \
               fontsize=14, loc='best', handlelength=6.5, handleheight=1.4, labelspacing=0.05, \
               handler_map={tuple: HandlerTuple(ndivide=None, pad=2)})
```

To format the column names like you show in your first picture use:

```py
# change marker and markersize
p11, = plt.plot([], marker=r'$k_{max}=0.3$', linestyle='None', color='k', markersize=45, mec='None')
p12, = plt.plot([], marker='$k_{max}=1.0$', linestyle='None', color='k', markersize=45, mec='None')

# change plt.legend, use 'borderpad' parameter to increase the legend box,
# otherwise part of the column name will be written out of bounds
#                                                                         | change here
l = plt.legend([(p11,p12),(p1,p6), (p2,p7), (p3,p8), (p4,p9), (p5,p10)], ['','$GC_{sp}$', \
               '$GC_{ph}$', '$WL$', '$GC_{ph} + WL + XC$', '$GC_{sp} + (GC_{ph} + WL + XC)$'], \
               fontsize=14, loc='best', handlelength=6.5, handleheight=1.4, labelspacing=0.05, \
               borderpad=0.6, # change here
               handler_map={tuple: HandlerTuple(ndivide=None, pad=2)})
```

This will result in:

[image: Part 2 alternative solution]

Comment: Thanks ! it works perfectly, I will award you as soon as possible.